# expected value, vat containing millions of marbles, continued

Tags: probability

1. A vat contains millions of marbles. 20% of them have the number “6” carved on them, and the rest have the number “17” carved on them.

a) We draw a marble from the vat. Find the expected value.

My thinking:

E(x)= 17*.8 + 6*.2 = 14.8

b) We draw out two marbles from the vat. Let X be the sum of the two numbers. Find the expected value.

My thinking:

Do I just multiply by "2" because it is the sum of two numbers?  So, 2(14.8)=

Comment: Yes, that's right.  (Technically, it's only correct if you replace the first marble after drawing, but because there are millions of marbles the effect of drawing without replacement is negligible.  In fact, you have to neglect it, because to take it into account, you'd have to know exactly how many marbles there are.)

Comment: ok, would that be the same idea for finding: variance, standard deviation, and moment generating function of X.     Just multiply by 2?   Thank you for the insight

Comment: I didn't say that.  The expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations.  Not everything in the world is linear, however.